# Netsuite : Suitlet deployed by one admin not visible to other admins

Tags: netsuite

Netsuite Suitlet Issue : While an admin deployed the suitelet in file cabinet and can run it on her machine, other admins like us cant see or call that suitlet from the ui. do you know whats happening here ? we tried to see permissions but cant seem to figure out whats going on !

Answer (score 2):

You need to check a couple of things on the *Deployment* record of the Suitelet:

1. Make sure the *Status* is *Released* instead of *Testing*. In *Testing* mode, only the Owner of the script has access to it.
2. Check the *Audience* tab, and make sure that any relevant Employees, Roles, Groups, etc that should have access to the Suitelet are selected